# Split duplicate email addresses in single excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have some data to maintain, that we can export (and import) again in Excel spreadsheets. Problem is, that we have to fix this data sets (mail addresses) inside Excel before importing. Some of these data sets have duplicated email addresses in a single cell. Some are space, colon or comma separated … and **some are not** at all.

Now we are trying to find an *Excel Formula* to split duplicated text in a single cell. **Example data:**

```
foo.bar@example.comfoo.bar@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a trigger that looks for the **@** character occurring twice in the cell, for example:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","")
```

This would return a value of 2 for duplicate cells, and 1 for good data.  Then for processing, do a quick `Ctrl+H` style removal of all the possible separator characters (space,comma,colon,etc.), and then you could just cut the text length of the offending cells in half.

Answer (score 1):

If this is simply trying to find if a single cell contains duplicated text, this simple formula will solve that specific problem, where the text in question is in cell A1:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/2),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/2))=A1,"Duplicated","Not Duplicated")
```

This simply concatenates the first half of the string twice and determines if it is the same as the full string. This formula WILL NOT work if the two duplicate strings are separated by some separator (unless that separator is also repeated).